# How can I recursively use phantomjs netlog.js to catch all url responses with ".js" and output the responses?

Tags: javascript, http, phantomjs, response

I have currently edited the netlog.js code to what is shown below:

```
"use strict";
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    address;

var resUrl;

if (system.args.length === 1) {
    console.log('Usage: netlog.js <some URL>');
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {
    address = system.args[1];

    page.onResourceRequested = function (req) {
       console.log('requested: ' + JSON.stringify(req, undefined, 4));
    };


    page.onResourceReceived = function (res) {
        resUrl = res["url"]  
        if (resUrl.indexOf(".js") !== -1){
            console.log('\nJS Call URL:' + resUrl);
            var page2 = require('webpage').create(), address2 = resUrl;
            page2.onResourceRequested = function (req2){
                console.log('\tLevel 2 requested: ' + JSON.stringify(req2, undefined, 4));
            };
            page2.onResouceReceived = function (req2){
                console.log('\t Level 2 URL:' + req2["url"]);
            };
        }
        else{
            console.log('URL:' + resUrl);
        }
    };

    page.open(address, function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('FAIL to load the address');
        }
        phantom.exit();
    });
}
```

However, it only outputs 1 Level of URL responses. I would like it to re-run netlog.js on those URLs with .js as that is what I am trying to do with the `if (resUrl.indexOf(".js") !== -1)` onwards piece of code. I cannot understand why a second webpage instance will not be created, and be able to re-run the code.

Comment: You're creating `page2`, but you forgot to open a page in it.

Comment: Please explain further what you mean by open it as I am following the code from http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/. Which does not have anything about opening a page after creating it

Comment: Of course it does. Why do you think, you need `page2.open(url, callback)`? You need to tell PhantomJS to navigate to a page somehow, but you're not doing that at all. Look through the code and check where you tell `page2` to navigate to a URL. Also, you're exiting too early. `phantom.exit()` should be called after the last page is loaded. Currently, you're exiting when the first page has loaded.